# assign to nested array in react state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi i try to do basic TODO app in React.
I have my state in App.js

```
state = {
   newBoxName: '',

   boardCollection: [
     {
       id: new Date().getTime(),
       title: 'testOne',
       Boxes: []
     }
   ]
 };
```

and on click i creat new board as new object in boardCollection in App.js

```
setNewBoard = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.setState(prev => ({
        boardCollection: [
          ...prev.boardCollection,

          { id: new Date().getTime(), title: "some user input",  Boxes: [] }
        ]
      }));

    }
  };
```

now i want to create new box and save it in Boxes(for each board different boxes) as new object. i try to search for a answer, but i just can't find a solution. i alo try:

```
onSubmitAddBox() {
    this.setState({
      boardCollection: {
        ...this.state.boardCollection,
        Boxes: {
          ...this.state.boardCollection.Boxes,
          title: this.state.newBoxName
        }
      }
    });
```

but it throw error this. is not defind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manage to solve this by creating a copy of state.boardCollection and maping thrue boardCollection, then check if id of maping element was same as id of element that i click on then a change the copy of boardCollection and set it to the state.

```
onSubmitAddBox = id => {
    this.state.boardCollection.map((elem, index) => {

      let boardCollection = { ...this.state.boardCollection };

      if (elem.id === id) {
        boardCollection[index].Boxes = [
          ...boardCollection[index].Boxes,
          { name: this.state.newBoxName }
        ];
        console.table(this.state.boardCollection);
        this.setState([boardCollection]);
        this.setState({ newBoxName: '' });
      }
    });
  };
```